# std::multimap::erase() while iterating

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::multimap` that maps session IDs (`int`s) to the pieces of hardware used in that session (the hardware is described by a `struct` that contains some hardware specific info).

I have a cleanup function that has to do specific cleanup stuff for each piece of hardware. After the cleanup is done, I need to erase that element from the map, since the hardware is no longer used in that session.

Note that I don't just want to remove a single piece of hardware from a session. Instead the whole session gets torn down, so I want to search the map for the session ID, cleanup the hardware, and remove all those entries from the map.

Here's some code which shows what I am trying to explain:

```
void MyClass::end_session(const int session_id) {
  // session_map_ is a member variable of MyClass
  const auto range = session_map_.equal_range(session_id);
  for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; session_map_.erase(it++)) {
    // do cleanup for the hardware pointed to by it->second
  }
}
```

Is the loop legal? I know that the iterator passed in to `erase()` gets invalidated, but this doesn't invalidate `range.first` or `range.second`, correct? Also, does `session_map_.erase(it++)` work like I would expect it to? That is, I'm assuming that `it` gets saved as the argument for `erase()`, gets incremented to its new value, and then `erase()` is called for the old value (thus invalidating the iterator before the increment). Is that correct?

Comment: Fyi,`std::multimap` has a [iterator-range-based erase method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase).

Comment: @WhozCraig Right, but I have to already loop over all the elements anyways, so I would prefer to use the `erase()` method which just takes the iterator position and does the operation in amortized constant time, instead of later calling the iterator-range based method which takes `log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last)` time and hoping that my compiler combines the loops when optimizing.

Comment: A safer way to do `session_map_.erase(it++)` would be `it = session_map_.erase(it)` -- `erase()` returns the next iterator after the erased one for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says

> Other references and iterators are not affected

So your loop runs as expected and `erase` works as expected.

Suppose you have 4 elements, in your case the loop runs 4 times without any problem.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is perfectly safe.

I, however, am leery of complex control flow in business logic.  It is too hard to understand at a glance, and comments have a risk of becoming out of sync.

As such I write verbs.

```
template<class C, class It, class F>
void erase_remove_if( C& c, It b, It e, F&& f) {
  auto it = b;
  while (it != e) {
    if (f(*it))
      it = c.erase(it);
    else
      ++it
  }
}
template<class C, class F>
void erase_remove_if( C& c, F&& f) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  return erase_remove_if( c, begin(c), end(c), std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

now your code reads like:

```
void MyClass::end_session(const int session_id) {
  // session_map_ is a member variable of MyClass
  const auto range = session_map_.equal_range(session_id);

  // remove said elements after doing some processing:
  erase_remove_if( session_map_, range.first, range.second, [&](auto& kv) {
    auto&& [key, elem] = kv;
    // do cleanup for the hardware pointed to by elem
    return true; // erase element
  });
}
```

basically fenceposting errors are so common and hard to prevent that I'd rather have my relatively complex loop control code in one spot.